# Ansible: Create variables from json string

Tags: json, ansible

In Ansible, is there a way to convert a dynamic list of key/value pairs that are located in a JSON variable into variable names/values that can be accessed in a Playbook without using the filesystem?

IE - If I have the following JSON in a variable (in my case, already imported from a URI call):

```
{
        "ansible_facts": {
            "list_of_passwords": {
                "ansible_password": "abc123",
                "ansible_user": "user123",
                "blue_server_password": "def456",
                "blue_server_user": "user456"
            }
}
```

Is there a way to convert that JSON variable into the equivelant of:

```
vars:
  ansible_password: abc123
  ansible_user: user123
  blue_server_password: def456
  blue_server_user: user456
```

Normally, I'd write the variable to a file, then import it using `vars_files:`. Our goal is to not write the secrets to the filesystem.

Comment: "*without using the filesystem*" -- Filesystem? What are you talking about? And what's the problem with accessing the values using a dotted path like `list_of_passwords.ansible_password`? You ask a very general question, but the example is too localised. You can use a template to convert the structure, case by case.

Comment: I think what I'm struggling with is the second part of your reply - converting the structure case-by-case. Assuming I don't know what the variables are in advance, how could I go about it case-by-case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [uri module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/uri_module.html) to make a call and then register response to variable:

For example:

```
- uri:
    url: http://www.mocky.io/v2/59667604110000040ec8f5c6
    body_format: json
  register: response
- debug:
    msg: "{{response.json}}"
- set_fact: {"{{ item.key }}":"{{ item.val }}"}
  with_dict: "{{response.json.ansible_facts.list_of_passwords}}"
```

Comment: In case of json from other source than `uri`, you can use the `from_json` filter: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data

Comment: The URI read I've got, what I'm trying to figure out is how to process the returned JSON object into variables who's names and keys are _in_ the JSON object.

Comment: You can dynamically set variables using `set_fact`. See my update.

Comment: Your update worked for me, though I had to use `with_dict` instead of `with_items`. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you're right, I haven't tested it yesterday, I corrected my answer.